# How to get Column reference from declarative table in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I use the *declarative* style to define my tables with SQLAlchemy.

```
Base = declarative_base()

class MyTable(Base):
    id = Column('someone_put_a_strange_for_id', Integer)
```

Now, when I define **ForeignKey** in the class, I need to use

```
MyTable.__table__.c.someone_put_a_strange_for_id
```

to refer to this *id* Column attribute. Is there any way I can use

```
MyTable.id.some_magic
```

to get this Column attribute?

Comment: Why not just use reference to the model (not the column): `ForeignKey(MyTable.id)`?

Comment: I tried, it does not work. Because the attribute name is different from the table field name.

Comment: Strange, this is the first easy option Mike mentioned in the answer and it always worked for me. Hope other options listed in Mike's answer will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two easy options here.

The simplest is, just refer to the attribute on the class!

```
Base = declarative_base()

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mt'
    id = Column('someone_put_a_strange_for_id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar = Column(Integer)

fk = ForeignKeyConstraint(['bar'], [MyTable.id])
```

This is not actually the `Column` object, however in virtually all situations, SQLAlchemy will look at this object for a special attribute called `__clause_element__()` which will pull out the actual `Column`.   In modern SQLAlchemy versions this should work just about everywhere, post a bug report if there's someplace it's not working.

The other is to put a .key on the column:

```
class MyTable(Base):
    id = Column('someone_put_a_strange_for_id', Integer, key='id')
```

Above, that column is now table.c.id in all in-Python cases, the "name" is only on the SQL side.  So if you are dealing with table.c directly, there you go.

There's still more options!  The mapper that's on your class also has its own `.c` attribute, you can get at it this way also:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect

Base = declarative_base()

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mt'
    id = Column('someone_put_a_strange_for_id', Integer, primary_key=True)

inspect(MyTable).c.id
```